# No rule to make target `distclean'. Stop when compile openresty

Tags: linux

When I am using this command to compile Openresty(1.13.6.2):

```
# configure openresty
./configure --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre-8.43 --with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl-1.0.2r --with-zlib=/usr/local/lib
# make openresty  
gmake
```

When execute this command,it throws this error:

```
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/openresty-1.13.6.2/build/lua-rds-parser-0.06'
gmake[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/openresty-1.13.6.2/build/lua-rds-parser-0.06'
cd /usr/local/openresty-1.13.6.2/build/nginx-1.13.6 && gmake
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/openresty-1.13.6.2/build/nginx-1.13.6'
gmake -f objs/Makefile
gmake[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/openresty-1.13.6.2/build/nginx-1.13.6'
cd /usr/local/lib \
        && gmake distclean \
        && CFLAGS="-O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe " CC="cc" \
                ./configure \
        && gmake libz.a
gmake[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/lib'
gmake[3]: *** No rule to make target `distclean'.  Stop.
gmake[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/lib'
gmake[2]: *** [/usr/local/lib/libz.a] Error 2
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/openresty-1.13.6.2/build/nginx-1.13.6'
gmake[1]: *** [build] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/openresty-1.13.6.2/build/nginx-1.13.6'
gmake: *** [all] Error 2
```

Where is going wrong？　How to fix this problem?

Comment: Contact the developers of this 'Openresty' as their make-process clearly broken: they should gmake anything in /usr/local/lib

Answer (score 0):

Use zlib source code folder to configure:

```
./configure --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre-8.43 --with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl-1.0.2r --with-zlib=/usr/local/zlib2.8-src
```

using the source folder,not the install output folder.